# Declaring Dictionary(Of Integer, AnonymousType) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, anonymous-types

I want to declare a vb.net dictionary with an integer as key and an anonymous object as value. This is filled by a parallel for each loop. The properties of the anonymous class are always the same. But is there a way to declare the dictionary with the signature of the anonymous object?

Right now, I'm using a Dictionary of integer and object.

```
Dim MyDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Integer, Object))(12)
'In my loop
Dim MyLinqDict = Something.GroupBy(…).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Kex, Function(x) New With {.a = 1, .b = 2})
MyDict.Add(MyKey, MyLinqDict)
```

Now, the obvious problem is, that the content of that inner dictionary is just an object. I neither know, if, and, if yes, how I can declare that inner dict with the actual object. Nor do I know, if I can typecast that "Object" as the anonymous type.

```
Dim MyContent = DirectCast(MyDict("Some key")(1), ???).a
```

Can somebody help me in this regard?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. It's anonymous or not. If you need to be able to cast and have definite access to property `a` then you need to define it instead of using object. If you want it anonymous you have to just trust that you aren't going to get any object that doesnt have `a`

Comment: Anonymous types are a Linq convenience.  They stop being convenient when you have to do this.  So don't do this, declare a little helper class to store the result.  Now it is simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If as you say, the properties are always going to be the same, just create a new class and populate it:

```
Dim MyDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Integer, MyObject))(12)

Dim MyLinqDict = Something.GroupBy(…).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Kex, Function(x) New MyObject With {.a = 1, .b = 2})

Public Class MyObject
    Public Property a() As Integer
    Public Property b() As Integer
End Class
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No. The type is unknown, because it is .. well anonymous.

If all values have the same number of items, Tuple can be used instead:

```
Dim d1 = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)))

Dim d2 = {1, 2}.ToDictionary(Function(i) i, Function(i) Tuple.Create(1, 2))

d1.Add(0, d2)

Dim MyContent = d1(0)(1).Item1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple POCO class. That is really the best solution.

Hypothetically speaking, you can use anonymous classes with generic type inference if you create some generic helper methods.

```
static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Create<TKey, TValue>(TKey sampleKey, TValue sampleValue)
{
    return new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
}

static TValue GetValueForKey<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key)
{
    return dic[key];
}

// Usage
var anonymousObject = new { a = "a_ok", b = "b_ok" };
var dic = Create(0, anonymousObject);   // Only creates the dictionary
dic.Add(1, anonymousObject);            // Adds a key/value pair

var value = GetValueForKey(dic, 1).a;   // Yields "a_ok"
```